# Creating array of arrays in loop in Perl

Tags: perl, csv

I'm trying to create an array-of-arrays with some data in a for loop.  The regex command in the code below helps me to gather the scalars that I will place in it.  As far as I know, that is correct, but when I try to output the @output array to a CSV file I receive a "Can't use string () as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use." error.  Is this because of the way I am creating the array or the way I'm trying to write it into a file?

```
foreach my $row(@input){
    my @cmd = qx("command");
    foreach my $line(@cmd){
        if($line =~ /regex/){
            push(@output, ($sp_name, $sp_port, $sp_type, $sp_uid)); 
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is what I am using to create my output file::

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new()
    or die "Cannot use Text::CSV ($!)";
my $file = "output.csv";
open my $fh, '>', $file
    or die "Cannot open $file ($!)";
$csv->eol("\n");
foreach my $row (@output)
{
    $csv->print($fh, \@{$row})
        or die "Failed to write $file ($!)";
}
close $fh
    or die "Failed to close $file ($!)";
```

Comment: After you apply the fixed mentioned below, change `\@{$row}` back to the simpler `$row`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pushing four scalars onto `@output`:

```
push(@output, ($sp_name, $sp_port, $sp_type, $sp_uid));
```

The parentheses do nothing but uselessly control precedence. Use square brackets:

```
push @output, [ $sp_name, $sp_port, $sp_type, $sp_uid ];
```

The [square brackets](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) create an array and return a reference to it.